# quiero ocultar un input cuando selecciono texto js

Tags: javascript, html

quiero ocultar un input date time para que cuando el usuario seleccione un opcion select que va ligado con otros opcion select este se habilite automaticamente

que seria este

```
var subCategorias = [

  {id:3,name:"Inti Raymi",idCategoria:2},
  {id:4,name:"Sr de los Milagros",idCategoria:2},
  {id:5,name:"chavin",idCategoria:3},
  {id:6,name:"caral",idCategoria:3},
  {id:7,name:"tacos",idCategoria:4},
  {id:8,name:"tacos",idCategoria:4},
  {id:9,name:"date",idCategoria:5  },
 {id:10,name:"promesa de pago",idCategoria:5},
  {id:11,name:"aqui ",idCategoria:6},

  
]
```

el if

```
if (subCategorias == "date"){
  document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = false;
         }
```

mi input

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="submitbutton"  disabled="disabled">
```

entonces cada que se seleccione el name:date quiero que se active el boton para poderlo ejecutar

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el ejemplo que te pase, creo que podrias implementarlo de esta manera, evaluar el index seleccionado y segun eso hacer un disabled true o false segun necesites.

En mi caso estoy diciendo si el valor de la comida es ceviche se habilite, pero ya estaria.

```js
var pais = [
  {id:1,name:"peru"},
  {id:2,name:"mexico"},
  {id:3,name:"españa"}
]

var categorias = [
  {id:1,name:"comida peruana",idPais:1},
  {id:2,name:"tradiciones peruanas",idPais:1},
  {id:3,name:"cultura peruana",idPais:1},
  {id:4,name:"comida mexico",idPais:2},
  {id:5,name:"tradiciones mexico",idPais:2},
  {id:6,name:"cultura mexico",idPais:2},
  {id:7,name:"comida españa",idPais:3},
  {id:8,name:"tradiciones españa",idPais:3},
  {id:9,name:"cultura españa",idPais:3},
]

var subCategorias = [
  {id:1,name:"ceviche",idCategoria:1},
  {id:2,name:"aji de gallina",idCategoria:1},
  {id:3,name:"Inti Raymi",idCategoria:2},
  {id:4,name:"Sr de los Milagros",idCategoria:2},
  {id:5,name:"chavin",idCategoria:3},
  {id:6,name:"caral",idCategoria:3},
  {id:7,name:"tacos",idCategoria:4},
  {id:8,name:"tacos",idCategoria:4},
  {id:9,name:"tacos",idCategoria:5},
  {id:10,name:"tacos",idCategoria:5},
  {id:11,name:"tacos",idCategoria:6},
  {id:12,name:"tacos",idCategoria:6},
  {id:13,name:"torbe",idCategoria:7},
  {id:14,name:"torbe",idCategoria:7},
  {id:15,name:"torbe",idCategoria:8},
  {id:16,name:"torbe",idCategoria:8},
  {id:17,name:"torbe",idCategoria:9},
  {id:18,name:"torbe",idCategoria:9},
]


//creando los options de area
var paisSelect = document.getElementById('pais');
var categoriasSelect = document.getElementById('categorias');
var subCategoriasSelect = document.getElementById('subCategorias');

paisSelect.addEventListener("change", cargarCategorias);
categoriasSelect.addEventListener("change", cargarSubCategorias); 
subCategoriasSelect.addEventListener("change", mostrarInput); 

pais.forEach(function(pais){
  let opcion = document.createElement('option')
  opcion.value = pais.id
  opcion.text = pais.name
  paisSelect.add(opcion)
})

function cargarCategorias(){
  categoriasSelect.options.length = 1;
  subCategoriasSelect.options.length = 1;
  categorias
  .filter(function (categoria){
      return categoria.idPais == this;
  }, paisSelect.value)
  .forEach(function(categoria){
    let opcion = document.createElement('option')
    opcion.value = categoria.id
    opcion.text = categoria.name
    categoriasSelect.add(opcion);
  });
}

function cargarSubCategorias(){
   subCategoriasSelect.options.length = 1;
   subCategorias
  .filter(function (subCategoria){
      return subCategoria.idCategoria == this;
  }, categoriasSelect.value)
  .forEach(function(subCategoria){
    let opcion = document.createElement('option')
    opcion.value = subCategoria.id
    opcion.text = subCategoria.name
    subCategoriasSelect.add(opcion);
  });
}

function mostrarInput(){
  var inputs= document.getElementsByClassName('submitbutton');
  if(subCategoriasSelect.options.selectedIndex == 1){
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
      inputs[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }else{
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
      inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="pais">Areas:</label>
<select id="pais">
  <option value="0">seleccione</option>
</select>
<br>

<label for="pais">Categorias:</label>
<select id="categorias">
  <option value="0">selecccione</option>
</select>
<br>

<label for="pais">Sub Categorias:</label>
<select id="subCategorias">
  <option value="0">selecccione</option>
</select>

<input type="datetime-local" class="submitbutton"  disabled="disabled">
<input type="datetime-local" class="submitbutton"  disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: jajaj gracias de nuevo ojla te llegen 500 puntos

Comment: jajaja lo hago con gusto, estuve buscando lo del input dentro del select pero no encontre nada por eso no comente, un saludo. Si puedes marcas como solucionado este y el anterior, gracias.

Comment: y para habilitar por ejemplo dos input <input type="datetime-local" id="submitbutton"  disabled="disabled">
<label for="monto">Monto:</label>
<input type="text" id="submitbutton"  disabled="disabled">

Comment: o hay forma de poder agregar dos inputs que uno se habilite en otro estatus

Comment: Claro, se puede es cuestion de que evalues solamente el select que escoges y ocultas o muestras los que deseas.

Comment: ya lo hice pero solo me manda por default uno je

Comment: con este function mostrarInput2(){
  if(subCategoriasSelect.options.selectedIndex == 2){
    document.getElementById('algo').disabled = false;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('algo').disabled = true;
  }
  
}

Comment: mira adapte el codigo a 2 input, recuerda que el id es un identificador unico, en tal caso si ambas cambiaran al mismo tiempo puedes usarlo como clase y recorrer ese arreglo. por otro lado si cada input es distinto para cada select si deberias usar un id diferente para cada uno y deberia funcionar.

Comment: lo use con el id 2 ya que cambia cuando quiero agregar una llamada pero no ejecuta el disiabled false

Comment: <input type="datetime-local" id="algo"  disabled="disabled"  class="submitbutton"required>

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113878/discussion-between-felipe-urcia-and-robert-josue-mendoza).